# Blank error in PHP 5.4 error log

Tags: php, apache

I have a weird error appearing (log only - the page appears to function correctly), and am not at all sure how to diagnose it:

```
[Wed Jan 21 10:44:39 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.84] , referer: http://<scrubbed>
```

Can anyone suggest what might cause this?

Comment: `the page appears to function correctly` then wats the issue?

Comment: I thing you should also add the `apache` tag to the question. PHP does not write to `error_log` (Apache does).

Comment: @axiac: OP did not specify what log this is being written to, so perhaps it's not the webserver, but the code that contains a bug, causing it to log empty strings?

Comment: Search your code for calls to `trigger_error` and functions which could possibly end up throwing an empty custom error message. It would surprise me greatly if this wasn't a custom error being triggered without a message.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem - it is Apache, I should have stated that, apologies.

Comment: @ɴᴀᴛʜ Just tried a grep for trigger_error throughout the code, no results. It's a relatively old project but I'll ask around for any custom errors that may have been inserted.